# POST request... UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

When making a post request I get this error:

***UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.***

If somebody could explain why this is happening I would appreciate it :) Thanks

***UPDATE***

So, the this code POSTs successfully. But, when I uncomment the validation code I get that same error...

```
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  //let client = validate(req.body);

  //if (client.error) {
    //res.status(400).json(result.error);
    //return;
  //}

  let client = new Client(req.body);

  try {
    let savedClient = await client.save();
    res.location(`/${savedClient._id}`).status(201).json(savedClient);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json(savedClient.error);
  }
});
```

Comment: Where do you get `result` from? (`result.error`)

Comment: That should be savedClient.error. I changed it but still the same issue.

Comment: what does `validate(req.body)` return? Can it throw an error or exception?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you initialise `savedClient` and I think your error lies in your catch. You're referencing an object (`savedClient`) which doesn't appear to be in scope.

Try this:

```
router.post("/", async (req, res) => { 
  let client = new Client(req.body);
  try {
    let savedClient = await client.save();
    res.location(`/${savedClient._id}`).status(201).json(savedClient);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    res.status(500).json(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: Check my updated code

Answer (score 0):

maybe

```
let savedClient = await client.save();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
...
} catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json(savedClient.error);
}
```

because the promise's rejection error should be catch by the try/catch statement.